# Setting Variables To Use With JavaScript Executor In Selenium Gives Variable Not Defined Error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to set a basic variable "a" to use with javascript executor in selenium, but gives a variable not defined error.

I dont know javascript, so not sure how to define a variable for javascript executor.

Thanks.,

```
a = 12

driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("FormRow-BUY-price").value=a;')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing this value to JS

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("FormRow-BUY-price").value='+str(a)+';')
```

This is one of many solutions, other might be string formatting or if you want this value to be accessible in js, you can do

```
driver.execute_script('a='+str(a)+';')
```

after any change of a variable

Comment: @GenusMax  : If this worked for you, Mark this as a accepted answer.